# How to add replace audio of video and loop audio if video duration is greater than audio duration in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am Replacing audio of my video file in FFmpeg with taking care of below two things:

while replacing audio of video

1. If the video duration is greater than the audio duration than repeat(loop) audio until the video ends.
2. If the video duration is less than the audio duration than take the required audio duration.

Comment: What should the video do if the audio is longer? Loop? Freeze frame?

Comment: suppose audio duration is 03:30 and video duration is 01:30 then it will take 01:30 duration of audio.do not repeat audio or Freeze frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop the audio and use `-shortest`:

```
ffmpeg -i video -stream_loop -1 -i audio -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -shortest output
```

Comment: your command not replacing old audio. output video still contains old audio not new audio

Comment: @MilanTejani See updated answer.

Comment: and what if I want to repeat specific audio duration in the video. is this possible. ex.. i have a audio of 5:30 min and I want to repeat 00:50 to 1:50 of audio duration in video

Comment: @MilanTejani Lazy answer is to trim the audio first, such as: `ffmpeg -ss 50 -i audio -t 60 -c copy output`, then run command in answer. Complicated answer is to refer to the atrim, asetpts, and aloop filters. Refer to documentation or search Stack Exchange for examples.

Comment: Possible to fadeout the audio at the end of the video?