# How to add audio every x time [ffmpeg]

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video-editing

I have a file video.mp4 and file audio.mp3, how to with the audio inserted every 2 seconds of video i try it but doesn't seem right. Please help me!

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -filter_complex "[1]adelay=2s:all=true[delayed];[0][delayed]amix=duration=shortest" -c:v copy output.mp4
```

Comment: You may use `-stream_loop` as in the [following answer](https://superuser.com/a/1540570/635712). If the audio is longer than 2 seconds, use [atrim](http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/atrim.htm.gz) filter instead of `adelay`. If you still need help, please add more details: How long is the video file? How long is the audio file? What do you mean by "audio inserted every 2 seconds"? Can you please add a drawing?